# Entering AuthUserFile info in .htaccess when root path is dynamic

Tags: apache, .htaccess, password-protection

I'm trying to follow the instructions on http://www.4webhelp.net/tutorials/misc/htaccess.php in order to create a password file placed outside of the web root and use it in conjunction with .htaccess. The problem I can't solve here is that the `AuthUserFile` info in .htaccess is supposed to be an absolute path to the server root. I am using a server provided by a web hosting company and I found using `<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>` that the complete path to my web root looks something like `/mumbo/jumbo/my_site/public_html` where `/mumbo/jumbo/` is stuff determined by the web host and, importantly, *subject to change without notice*.

In PHP I can of course generate a path that always is correct using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. But .htaccess is not written in PHP. Is there a similar way to obtain the server root path upstream of the web root dynamically using the syntax of .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual:

> File-path is the path to the user file. If it is not absolute, it is
>   treated as relative to the ServerRoot.

You should give either an absolute path or a relative one to the server root. Neither would solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. Please forgive my ignorance, but as I want to point to a password file which, for security reasons, is outside the web root, can I use a `../` expression then?
Say that the password file is to be placed in `my_site/not_public/` which is a sibling folder to the web root `my_site/public_html`. Can I write `AuthUserFile ../not_public/.htpasswd`as the path?

Comment: Afraid not. I just tried that and got an Internal Server Error message back. Hardcoding the `/mumbo/jumbo/` path worked. So I' still left with my problem. I would have imagined there is a solution.

Comment: Sorry I'm not at all experienced with server work. Where can I find the error log?

Comment: I misread the documentation. I thought about `DocumentRoot` when I was reading `ServerRoot`.